# Sass Mixin linear gradient with image (url)

Tags: image, url, sass, gradient

I'm trying to create a mixin in Sass in order to get both a gradient linear from top to bottom within a svg image on a div.

First I tried with a linear gradient mixin like this:

```
@mixin linear-gradient($fromColor, $toColor) {
  background-color: $toColor;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from($fromColor), to($toColor));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, $fromColor, $toColor);
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, $fromColor, $toColor);
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, $fromColor, $toColor);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, $fromColor, $toColor);
  background-image:         linear-gradient(top, $fromColor, $toColor);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#{$fromColor}', EndColorStr='#{$toColor}');
}
```

Then I'm using it in the code with severals attempts without any success:

```
.class { @include background(url("../img/cryptocurrency.svg") no-repeat, linear-gradient(#5BFE77, #00B807)); }
```

Then,

```
.class { @include linear-gradient(#5BFE77, #00B807), url("../img/cryptocurrency.svg") no-repeat; }
```

At last,

```
.class { @include linear-gradient(#5BFE77, #00B807); background: url("../img/cryptocurrency.svg") no-repeat; }
```

Nothing worked. So I started to look around the web (even on Stackoverflow) and I tried to add the Bourbon mixin on my toolsets (I didn't installed Bourbon or Compass):

```
@mixin background-image($images...) {
  $webkit-images: ();
  $spec-images: ();

  @each $image in $images {
    $webkit-image: ();
    $spec-image: ();

    @if (type-of($image) == string) {
      $url-str:       str-slice($image, 1, 3);
      $gradient-type: str-slice($image, 1, 6);

      @if $url-str == "url" {
        $webkit-image: $image;
        $spec-image:   $image;
      }

      @else if $gradient-type == "linear" {
        $gradients: _linear-gradient-parser($image);
        $webkit-image:  map-get($gradients, webkit-image);
        $spec-image:    map-get($gradients, spec-image);
      }

      @else if $gradient-type == "radial" {
        $gradients: _radial-gradient-parser($image);
        $webkit-image: map-get($gradients, webkit-image);
        $spec-image:   map-get($gradients, spec-image);
      }
    }

    $webkit-images: append($webkit-images, $webkit-image, comma);
    $spec-images:   append($spec-images,   $spec-image,   comma);
  }

  background-image: $webkit-images;
  background-image: $spec-images;
}
```

+

```
@mixin linear-gradient($pos, $g1, $g2: null,
                       $g3: null, $g4: null,
                       $g5: null, $g6: null,
                       $g7: null, $g8: null,
                       $g9: null, $g10: null,
                       $fallback: null) {
  // Detect what type of value exists in $pos
  $pos-type: type-of(nth($pos, 1));
  $pos-spec: null;
  $pos-degree: null;

  // If $pos is missing from mixin, reassign vars and add default position
  @if ($pos-type == color) or (nth($pos, 1) == "transparent")  {
    $g10: $g9; $g9: $g8; $g8: $g7; $g7: $g6; $g6: $g5;
    $g5: $g4; $g4: $g3; $g3: $g2; $g2: $g1; $g1: $pos;
    $pos: null;
  }

  @if $pos {
    $positions: _linear-positions-parser($pos);
    $pos-degree: nth($positions, 1);
    $pos-spec:   nth($positions, 2);
  }

  $full: $g1, $g2, $g3, $g4, $g5, $g6, $g7, $g8, $g9, $g10;

  // Set $g1 as the default fallback color
  $fallback-color: nth($g1, 1);

  // If $fallback is a color use that color as the fallback color
  @if (type-of($fallback) == color) or ($fallback == "transparent") {
    $fallback-color: $fallback;
  }

  background-color: $fallback-color;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient($pos-degree $full); // Safari 5.1+, Chrome
  background-image: unquote("linear-gradient(#{$pos-spec}#{$full})");
}
```

Then I fixed my code compared to what the doc said:

```
.class { @include background-image(url("../img/cryptocurrency.svg"), linear-gradient(white 0, yellow 50%, transparent 50%)); }
```

As a result nothing works.

Here's the errors my compiler showed. If someone want to Backtrace feel free to ask.

```
Error: $map: "_linear-gradient-parser(linear-gradient(white 0, yellow 50%, transparent 50%))" is not a map for `map-get' on line 120 of /Library/WebServer/Documents/eureka/template/css/mixins.scss, in `background-image' from line 331 of /Library/WebServer/Documents/eureka/template/css/main.scss from line 13 of /Library/WebServer/Documents/eureka/template/css/layout.scss Use --trace for backtrace.
```

**TL;DR:** I'm looking for a custom mixin for gradient which support background image url in order to display a picture behind the gradient.

Help would be gratefully appreciated.

**[EDIT] 1:** I didn't installed Bourbon or Compass. I copied pasted the mixin code from their Github [Background Image](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/css3/_background-image.scss) and [Linear Gradient](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/8e7e36e01c47194d83951fb6315c5b26a008f2b7/app/assets/stylesheets/css3/_linear-gradient.scss). I don't want to install any of them. I'm just looking for a custom mixin that work fine with both gradient and background image.

**[EDIT] 2:** In this thread I'm explaining who I tried to achieve my goal. It doesn't mean I want to use Bourbon's code or even Compass. I meant I'm looking for a mixin (custom) that works. I searched the web without any clue. The only answer I had was about Bourbon and Compass that's why I tried to copy paste the code.

Comment: So I forgot to import a function from the Bourbon Source code right? As I'm looking for a custom mixin (for gradient and background image url) is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Did you not read the error message?  This has nothing to do with mixins or gradients.  You are trying to use the `map-get` function on a string when it requires a mapping.  That's what the error is telling you.  Sass doesn't care where the mapping comes from.

Comment: I'm newbie with Sass. I didn't understand the error. What should I do?